# How to remove list from Subscription Center in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscription-center

In my Subscription Center, I have a few lists, I need to remove those from Subscription Center rather than deleting the lists.

What are the options I have here? and how to remove the lists.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the list settings, and mark it as Private / unmark as Public.

> ListTypes:
>
> - Master: All Subscribers list
> - Private: List that does not display in the default profile center
> - Public: List that displays in the default profile center
> - Group: A group based on a list
> - Other: Triggered Send, Salesforce, or Microsoft Dynamics CRM hidden lists

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_as_lists.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thank you @zuzannamj it's worked